# how to pass array values to Formik select

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik for a bunch of admin console forms that I have in my application. So far I did not have this use case.

My Formik forms use one of 2 custom components, either a Myinputtext(input box) or a MySelect(drop down). I dont have a need for any other components so far. Here is how my Myselect component looks like.

```
const MySelect = ({ label, ...props }) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField(props);
      return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{label}</label>
        <select className={props.className} {...field} {...props}  />
        {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
          <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Over in the form I am passing values to this component like this

```
<MySelect className="select-input" label="Losing Player" name="losingPlayer">
                          <option value="">Select Losing Player</option>
                          <option value="player1">{state.Player1Name}  </option>
                          <option value="player2">{state.Player2Name}  </option>
```

All of this works for a few forms I have built so far. In the fourth form now, data coming back from the back end is coming as an array and I am trying to pass the array as input to the myselect component

```
<MySelect className="select-input" label="Losing Player" name="losingPlayer">
                              <option value="">Select Losing Player</option>
                              <option value="player1">{name of array object}  </option>
```

This is failing and not providing the right result.

In the formik official docs it says there is a way to handle array objects like this

```
<Form>
         <Field name="friends[0]" />
         <Field name="friends[1]" />
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </Form>
     </Formik>
```

But my array size can be dynamic and I cannot hardcode, 0,1 like above.

I tried rendering the array inside the select component like this,

```
    <MySelect className="select-input" label="Winning Player" name="winningPlayer"> 
{props.initialValues.map((player) => { 
<option key={player} value={player}> {player} </option> })} </MySelect>
```

this does not throw any errors. but the drop down is displayed empty.

I am basically hoping to have the names in the array displayed as the dropdown. What is the right solution to tackle this?

This finally worked:-

```
return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{label}</label>
        {!props.player ? <select className={props.className} {...field} {...props}  /> 
        : 
        <select className={props.className}>
           {props.player.map((player) => {
               return (
                   <option key={player} value={player}>
                       {player} 
                   </option>
               )
           })} 
         </select>
        }
        {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
          <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your array and render options inside your select like this:

```
{options?.map(({ value }) => (
  <option key={value} value={value}>
    {value}
  </option>
 ))}
```

Comment: hey man i had tried this earlier. But the select was showing as blank. Tried troubleshooting but was unable to crack it. Here is the code i tried earlier <MySelect className="select-input" label="Winning Player" name="winningPlayer">
                    {props.initialValues.map((player) => {
                        <option key={player} value={player}>
                            {player}
                        </option>
                    })}

                 </MySelect>

Comment: do it inside `MySelect` component, so options will be inside <select>